# Finding integers satisfying an equation.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratics

> Suppose $p$ is a prime greater than $3$. Find all pairs of integers $(a,b)$ satisfying the equation $$a^2+3ab+2p(a+b)+p^2=0$$

A good way to start (probably) was to complete the square, 
$$p^2+2p(a+b)+a^2+2ab+b^2+ab-b^2=0$$
$$\implies (p+a+b)^2=b(b-a)$$ 
$$\implies ab=b^2-(p+a+b)^2$$
$$\implies ab=(p+a+2b)(-p-a)$$
But here I'm stuck, this last equality strongly suggests a solution in negative integers, but I am unable to find it..

Aside from this, I have also managed to obtain that
$$b(2p+3a)<0$$
I don't know if it helps though..

Comment: Also prime $p$ divides $a^2+3ab=a(a+3b)$ so that $p|a$ or $p|a+3b$. Maybe that can help (I didn't try it out).

Comment: @drhab could you explain further?

Comment: If $p|uv$ and $p$ is prime then $p|u$ or $p|v$.

Comment: @drhab Of course I know that, I was asking how you would use it to solve the problem

Comment: You could go on by exploring the possibilities $a=kp$ and $a+3b=kp$. That's all. Maybe it bears some fruit. It will not be by accident that $p$ is a prime. This is a way to exploit that. I do not see any other exploitation of it in your question yet.

Comment: @drhab I obtain that either $$b(4+3k)>0$$ or $$b(2+3k)<0$$, I might have overlooked something useful :/

Comment: $a$ and $b$ both cannot be of the same parity.

Comment: @Dhruv yes that's true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

$$a^2+(2p+3b)a+p^2+2pb=0$$

Since $a$ is a integer, $\Delta$(the polynomial discriminant) 
is a square.

This implies $$(2p+3b)^2-4(p^2+2pb)=x^2$$For some integer $x$.

Thus $$4pb+9b^2=x^2 \Leftrightarrow 81b^2+36bp=9x^2 \Leftrightarrow (9b+2p)^2-4p^2=9x^2$$

Now, $$(9b+2p)^2-9x^2=4p^2$$

However, soltuions to $4p^2=t^2-u^2=(t+u)(t-u)$ are $(|t|,|u|)=( 2p, 0)$ and $( p^2+1, p^2-1)$

Comment: Now $p^2=t^2-u^2=(t+u)(t-u)$. This implies that either $u=0,t=p$ or $|t|=\frac{p^2+1}{2}$, $|u|=\frac{p^2-1}{2}$.

Comment: How do you say :$$4pb+9b^2=x^2 \Leftrightarrow 81b^2+36bp=4x^2 \Leftrightarrow (9b+2p)^2-4p^2=4x^2$$

Comment: @Nikunj Is it right now?

Comment: Are the solutions (2p,0) and $(p^2+1,p^2-1)$ the only ones possible?

Comment: @Nikunj Yes, if they are both positive. Because $x^2-y^2=4p^2=(x+y)(x-y)$. It follows that $(x-y,x+y)=(1,4p^2)(2,2p^2)(4,p^2)(4p,p),(2p,2p)(p,4p)(p^2,4),(2p^2,2)(4p^2,1)$.

Comment: @Nikunj But since $x+y \equiv x-y \pmod 2$, $1 \not \equiv 4p^2$, $4 \not \equiv p^2$, $4p \not \equiv p \pmod 2$. Also $x>y$. So the only cases left are $(2,2p^2)(2p,2p)

Comment: Yes, this would do it thanks!